# Animation alpha /&gt; String role

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml

In the animation file of a project there is this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha>
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:fillBefore="true"/&gt;
    </alpha>
</set>
```

Everything seems ok but I haven't clear what is the point of `/&gt;` here. This string should encode a `>` sign.
Is this an error or it has some special function I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You are correct its > sign
```

It would be like this. This is the copy paste issue sometimes with the Mac OS system.

Option 1 -As per XML added in question-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <alpha
            android:duration="500"
            android:fillBefore="true"
            android:fromAlpha="1"
            android:toAlpha="0" >
</alpha>
    </set>
```

Option 2 - for code refactoring scope-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <alpha
            android:duration="500"
            android:fillBefore="true"
            android:fromAlpha="1"
            android:toAlpha="0" />
    </set>
```

Comment: The alpha block is already enclosed with `</alpha>` that is the same of using `/>` so you are confirming that is an error and should be just removed.

Comment: @AndreaF updated answer with both options

Comment: @AndreaF must remove > from <alpha> which is stating of animation file.